# When bootstrapping percent differences, why is this for-loop faster than purrr:map?

Tags: r

For an analysis I’m running, the important stat of interest is the percent difference between two subgroups that exist within each of several groups.

I want to bootstrap the percent difference and while the first stab was a for loop that took 45 minutes total (on the order of 10’s of thousands of observations per treatment over 10 groups), I thought a purrr:map would be faster. It turns out it’s not, and I’m wondering what I’ve done wrong or if I should expect this behavior.

The closest built-in dataset I could reproduce this on was `warpbreak`, a breaking count between two yarns (subgroups) at different tensions (groups). See below for the example. While I wasn’t rigorous on timing stats, I was seeing about 100x improved speed in the loop vs the map.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tictoc)
library(ggplot2)
library(boot)

set.seed(1337)

test_data <- warpbreaks

test_data %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=tension, y=breaks, color = wool))



# bootstrap the relative (percent) difference
# in this case Wool A vs. Wool B

reldiff <- function(d, i) {
  
  m1 <- d[i,] %>% 
    filter(wool == "B") %>% 
    select(breaks) %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    unname() %>%
    mean()
  m0 <- d[i,] %>% 
    filter(wool == "A") %>% 
    select(breaks) %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    unname() %>%
    mean()
  
  (m1-m0)/m0
}

big_nest <- test_data %>%
  group_by(tension) %>%
  nest()


n_repetitions = 1000

tic()
test_boot <- big_nest %>%
  dplyr::mutate(booted = purrr::map(.x = data, # The list-column containing <S3: tibble>
                                    ~ boot::boot(data = .x, # The <S3 tibble> column being sampled
                                                 statistic = reldiff, # The user-defined function
                                                 R = n_repetitions, # The number of replicates
                                                 stype = "i")$t %>% quantile(c(0.025, 0.975)))) 
toc(log=TRUE)

test_boot$booted

# [[1]]
#          2.5%       97.5% 
#   -0.54953761 -0.09286544 
# 
# [[2]]
#         2.5%      97.5% 
#   -0.1314650  0.6325054 
# 
# [[3]]
#         2.5%      97.5% 
#   -0.4379570  0.0589989 

### for loop version

reldiff_loop <- function(b, a){
  (mean(b)-mean(a))/mean(a)
}

bootstrapper <- function(df, field = "breaks", stratum, filter, grouper, n_times = 1000){
  subset = df[which(pull(df, stratum) == filter), ]
  b_vec = pull(subset, field)[which(pull(subset, grouper)=="B")]
  a_vec = pull(subset, field)[which(pull(subset, grouper)=="A")]
  theta = reldiff_loop(b_vec, a_vec)
  thetahat = rep(0,times = n_times)
  for (j in 1:n_times){     
    thetahat[j] = reldiff_loop(mean(sample(b_vec,replace = TRUE)), mean(sample(a_vec,replace =TRUE)))
  }
  bounds = quantile(theta-thetahat, probs = c(0.025, 0.975)) %>% unname()
  thL = theta - bounds[2]
  thU = theta - bounds[1]
  # print(paste('The 95% BBootstrap CI for ',i,'is:',thL,thU))
  return(paste0(round(c(thL, thU),4), collapse = ", "))
}

tic()
z <- NULL
for(i in c("L", "M", "H")){
  z <- rbind(z, bootstrapper(test_data, 
                             field = "breaks", 
                             stratum = "tension", 
                             filter = i, 
                             grouper = "wool", 
                             n_times = n_repetitions))
}
toc(log=T)

z

#      [,1]              
# [1,] "-0.5469, -0.0952"
# [2,] "-0.1181, 0.6155" 
# [3,] "-0.4225, 0.0403" 

# ~100x faster on one sample
data.frame(trial = c("purrr", "for-loop"), time = unlist(tic.log()))

#    trial               time
#    purrr  20.18 sec elapsed
# for-loop    0.2 sec elapsed
```

Open to any suggestions. Or maybe the for-loop is the way to go

Comment: This is an apples to oranges comparison.  You're attributing the difference to the looping method but the difference is actually because you're using a different function in each (a sophisticated function that calculates and returns a lot more information than you're ultimately extracting vs a much more simplified approach that has relatively few calculations).

Comment: In general, purrr::map will not be any faster than a properly initialized for loop.  All the apply/map functions are essentially loops with simpler syntax.  Vectorize if possible, speed-up the function inside the loop, or loop in parallel for significantly better speed.

Comment: Good call-out on the apples to oranges, @Ritchie. I got so wrapped up in the loop vs map, I lost track of the underlying pieces.